Move Gizmo is not constrained to the corresponding axis
If you press G you can move the selected object in all directions. You can constrain the move to an axis by pressing X, Y or Z after the G. But I don't like that method too much. I prefer the actual gizmo, the move tool with the arrows, or the circles for rotation, or the one for scaling, with all three axes showing clearly, and in great part I like that better because it shows me where the object's axes are, but mostly because I can easily click and drag the red arrow and I know my movement of the object is going to be constrained to the X axis.
Well, I don't know if I changed something by accident in the preferences or what did I do, but for a few days now, if I click and drag on any of the arrows, it doesn't constrain the movement to the X axis, it just lets me drag it anywhere in any axis as if I had pressed G.
I keep going up and down the preferences and I still can't find what I did. Help me figure it out please?
And by the way, is there a way to assign a letter to enable each of the gizmos, like many 3D programs have Q to bring up the move tool, W for the rotate tool, and E for the scale one. I went through the whole list of key shortcuts and I can't find it.

No idea what you might have changed, but for your second question hover over any of the tool icons and you'll see the shortcut to select the gizmo. Shift-Space + G to bring up the Move gizmo, Shift-Space + R for Rotate etc.

Pretty sure that axis unlocked thing isn’t supposed to happen.

Shift+Space+G brings me a small menu where I can choose the different gizmos. In fact, just Shift and Space does that. But if press the three keys together, I still don't switch to the move gizmo, unless I click on it in that menu.

There must be something wrong with your keymap in that case. You could try File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings but that will overwrite any other settings you have changed from the default setup. I never use the gizmo here so can't comment further.

It might be a little misunderstable what @JohnEason posted there, I can relate to that - I usually use the "+" as well to show some keys should be pressed together. What you have to do (and I would maybe have written Shift+Space > G) is pressing Shift+Space together to bring up the menu, then release those keys and press G (or R or S) afterwards to select the tool and get the gizmos. Anyway, if you want to enable some gizmos permanently without switching to the tool, you can enable them in the Viewport Gizmos menu (left of the Overlays menu).

@GordonBrinkmann That comment was written late at night so give me some slack! :^)

@JohnEason Never mind, I think it could have been guessed by the OP if he had looked at the shortcuts behind the tool names in the menu ;) (I never use gizmos either, by the way)
